# How can i get all installed instances of Ms Office (Word, Excel, Power Point) in c#?

Tags: ms-office

I am working on a Win forms application. In my app user will have the ability to launch different version of MS office software (Word (2010, 2013), Excel (2010, 2013), Power point (2010, 2013)) from my application.

**What I have tried:**

I have used Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application, below is sample

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application appVersion = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
string version = appVersion.Version.ToString();
```

but the issue is that it returns only 1 version which is set to default, i need all the Ms word instances which are installed in my system.

**Question:**
How can i get all installed instances of Ms Office (Word, Excel, Power Point) in c# ?

Answer (score 0):

With you solution you only get the last installed instance.
This is because the last registered COM-Object will answer.

The last one is stored in this registry key:
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Word.Application
at these key there is at least a folder "CLSID" this points to the object.

All office versions have the same names and class id's.
This is a problem to find them thru the COM-system.

I think it es more elegant to query the windows installer by the office upgrade code using the [MsiEnumRelatedProducts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370103(v=vs.85).aspx) or [MsiEnumProductsEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370102(v=vs.85).aspx).

This will return all related product since office 2000 or later which are installed or advertised (install on demand).

There are [a lot of other functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369426(v=vs.85).aspx) where you can query install states and install folders.